# Что почитать ,чтобы понять как создавать приложения на javascript на основе МVС

Tags: javascript, mvc

В каких книгах вы встречали данную главу?
Какая схема разработки приложений?
Искал по гуглу,так поиск сводится к сравнению фреймворков и общей теории МVC.

Comment: > "поиск сводится к сравнению фреймворков и общей теории МVC"

А этого мало?

Comment: хочется  практику увидеть

Comment: @koza4ok - устройтесь на работу, либо начните что-то писать сами, разве не очевидно?

Comment: Кому я нужен такой без знаний MVC.Ну в общем кто встречал главу в книгах скажите автора.Всем спасибо

Comment: Да практика на реальных приложениях это лучший вариант.AlexWindHope

Comment: @koza4ok - вы не правы, например, если-бы я подбирал JS программистов на проект, то вопрос MVC, мягко говоря, не был-бы решающим

Comment: @AlexWindHope, просто интересно(не мне одному), что важнее?=)

Comment: @Spectre - думал это очевидно, но, судя по всему нет... В первую очередь - знание и понимание языка и опыт. Вообще, по моему скромному убеждению, MVC не панацея, прискорбно то, что, до сих пор, абсолютное большинство этого не понимает

Answer (score 5, accepted):

МVC - это всего лиш подход разделения ответсвенности в вашем коде(данные отделены от представления), и от того, как вы реализуете это разделение будет зависит что вы получите, это доказывает пара десятков MV* фреймворков.

в этом вопросе нет строгих правил, поэтому посмотрите на уже существующие решения - [TodoMVC](http://addyosmani.github.com/todomvc/) - попробуйте реализовать некоторую задачу сами и в конечном счёте у вас сложиться хоть какое-то мнение на счёт того, какой фреймворк(или его отсутствие) когда использовать(чужие мнения можно посмотреть в статье [Journey Through The JavaScript MVC Jungle](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2012/07/27/journey-through-the-javascript-mvc-jungle/) на хабре вроде был перевод).

**хорошей** литературы не много:

- [Developing Backbone.js Applications](http://addyosmani.github.com/backbone-fundamentals/) бывший Backbone fundamentals
- [Маккоу А. - Веб-приложения на JavaScript](http://rutracker.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=4201240), оригинал - [MacCaw A. - JavaScript Web Applications](http://rutracker.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=3762277)

Comment: спасибо за литературу